# Keep active jQuery UI tab and related to it sub-tab after reloading page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to keep active jQuery UI tab and related to it sub-tab after reloading page.
Currently, I keep only tabs.

I use next script:

```
$(".tabs").tabs({
    active: localStorage.getItem("currentIdx"),
    activate: function (event, ui) {
    localStorage.setItem("currentIdx", $(this).tabs('option','active'));
               }});
```

https://codepen.io/evgenydym/pen/YvGRER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using storing value in sessionstorage:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/PaGerK

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = "0";
    var j ="0";
      $tab = $(".tabs").tabs({  
         activate : function (e, ui) {
            tabid = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
            if(tabid.indexOf("sub") != -1){
              sessionStorage.setItem('sub-tab-index', ui.newPanel.attr('id'));
            }else{
                sessionStorage.setItem('tab-index', ui.newPanel.attr('id'));
            }
         }
    });

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('tab-index') != null) {
        i = sessionStorage.getItem('tab-index');
        if(i !=''){
            $('.tabs li').each(function(){
             var ac =  $(this).attr('aria-controls');

             if(ac.indexOf("sub") == -1){
                $(this).removeClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active");
                console.log(ac)
                console.log($('#'+ ac).css('display', 'none'));
             }
           });
            $("#"+i).css('display','block');
            $('.tabs').find("[aria-controls='"+i+"']").find('a').trigger('click');
           $('.tabs').find("[aria-controls='"+i+"']").addClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
           //sessionStorage.removeItem('tab-index')
        }
    }

   if (sessionStorage.getItem('sub-tab-index') != null) {
         j = sessionStorage.getItem('sub-tab-index');
         if(j !=''){
             $('.tabs li').each(function(){
                 var ac1 =  $(this).attr('aria-controls');
                 if(ac1.indexOf("sub") != -1){
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active");
                 }
               });

            $('.tabs').find("[aria-controls='"+j+"']").find('a').trigger('click');
            $('.tabs').find("[aria-controls='"+j+"']").addClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
          //  sessionStorage.removeItem('sub-tab-index');
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Your example related to tabs, but I am interested to know how to implement the same for sub-tabs.